# Why is my object showing up at undefined,but it exists! react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am calling an array of objects via react-redux and setting them equal to programList, on a higher level component then passing it in here, I set the object id found to a variable via find() and I'm trying to console.log the info.

When I call the programList, it's fine, and sometimes when I call the selectedProgram, it will show up as undefined, already weird cause I never had that happen just last week.

The kicker is when I just wanna test if I can get the title from the single returned object(selectedProgram) with selectedProgram.title I get undefined and when I do a Object.keys(I get an undefined).

I have tried putting it inside a new promise and it will work, but I also get an unresolved promise warning. But I'm loss since I didn't change this particular code but it won't work.

```js
20:23:32: Incoming Program Id:  5e8860c0-cbe7-11e8-bca0-b7f8a21d1c09
20:23:32: 5e8860c0-cbe7-11e8-bca0-b7f8a21d1c09 5e8860c0-cbe7-11e8-bca0-b7f8a21d1c09
```

```js
const Workout = ({ programList, programId }) => {
  // find the correct programlist with same id as navId for mapping
  const selectedProgram = programList.find(index => {
    if (index.id === programId) {
      console.log(programId, index.id);
      return index;
    }
  });

  // const workoutListArr = selectedProgram;
  console.log("this is the original list", programList);
  console.log("this is object: ", selectedProgram);
  console.log("this is here: ", selectedProgram.title);
```

```js
20:21:43: this is the original list Array [
20:21:43:   Object {
20:21:43:     "description": "description",
20:21:43:     "difficulty": "#FFDF00",
20:21:43:     "id": "0e772ff0-c785-11e8-92f8-274c004a8b60",
20:21:43:     "title": "Shrug",
20:21:43:     "workouts": Array [
20:21:43:       Object {
20:21:43:         "description": "description",
20:21:43:         "difficulty": "#FFDF00",
20:21:43:         "id": "15618310-c785-11e8-92f8-274c004a8b60",
20:21:43:         "title": "YouTube",
20:21:43:         "workouts": Array [],
20:21:43:       },
20:21:43:       Object {
20:21:43:         "description": "description",
20:21:43:         "difficulty": "#d9534f",
20:21:43:         "id": "189a18d0-c785-11e8-92f8-274c004a8b60",
20:21:43:         "title": "Empty Title",
20:21:43:         "workouts": Array [],
20:21:43:       },
20:21:43:     ],
20:21:43:   },
20:21:43:   Object {
20:21:43:     "description": "Master",
20:21:43:     "difficulty": "#FFDF00",
20:21:43:     "id": "5e8860c0-cbe7-11e8-bca0-b7f8a21d1c09",
20:21:43:     "title": "Red",
20:21:43:     "workouts": Array [
20:21:43:       Object {
20:21:43:         "description": "It",
20:21:43:         "difficulty": "#FFDF00",
20:21:43:         "id": "e1ab31d0-cbf1-11e8-aaa1-3fb0ac98f560",
20:21:43:         "title": "Redd",
20:21:43:         "workouts": Array [],
20:21:43:       },
20:21:43:       Object {
20:21:43:         "description": "World ",
20:21:43:         "difficulty": "#FFDF00",
20:21:43:         "id": "20cf8930-cc1d-11e8-8d7e-172d4a63fd8f",
20:21:43:         "title": "Hello",
20:21:43:         "workouts": Array [],
20:21:43:       },
20:21:43:     ],
20:21:43:   },
20:21:43: ]
20:21:43: this is object:  undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.find` works a little differently. The callback is called for each item and returns the first one that is true

```js
var programList = [{id: "1"},{id:"2"}];

(( programList, programId ) => {

console.log(programId);

  // find the correct programlist with same id as navId for mapping
  const selectedProgram = programList.find(index => {
    if (index.id === programId) {
      console.log(programId, index.id);
      return true;
    }
     return false;
  });

  console.log(selectedProgram);

})(programList, "2")
```

Comment: that way works also, however for i still unable to get the key values, it says undefined when I try any selectedProgram.title, etc.

Comment: thank for the attempt, I figured out the problem, the id to compare it to was in a higher level component and i didn't realize i set it to componentdid mount, instead of willmount, so when the find searched it didn't have an id to compare to immediately.